# supportFragmentManager not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, material-design

I am trying to use **bottom sheet fragment  in another fragment**

So **supportFragmentManager** is showing error in code below (because it doesn't work with fragment)

```
override fun onMapLongClick(point: LatLng)  {
    try {
        CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment().apply {
            show(supportFragmentManager, CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment.TAG)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I tried

```
* childSupportManager
* requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
* activity.supportFragmentManager
* parentFragmentManager
* (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
```

nothing worked

CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment

```
    package com.example.weatherapp.ui.dashboard

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.weatherapp.R
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layout_modal_bottom_sheet.*

class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    companion object {

        const val TAG = "CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment"

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_modal_bottom_sheet, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        firstButton.setOnClickListener {
            //handle click event
            Toast.makeText(context, "First Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        secondButton.setOnClickListener {
            //handle click event
            Toast.makeText(context, "Second Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        thirdButton.setOnClickListener {
            //handle click event
            Toast.makeText(context, "Third Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        }
     }
```

It shows the error

```
    W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment{37cafe5} 
                  (1887523f-4ffe-4232-bacc-d4114dcfe8a4)} has not been attached yet.
                  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getChildFragmentManager(Fragment.java:980)
                  at com.example.weatherapp.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment.onMapLongClick(DashboardFragment.kt:163)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzz.onMapLongClick(Unknown Source:2)
                  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzao.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:5)
```

Comment: Please share your `CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment` code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this below code:

```
val manager: FragmentManager =
    (this.context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
       CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment().show(manager, TAG)
```

And in `CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment` class:

```
class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment() : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
  //code
}
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221554/discussion-between-ali-and-mohit-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

supportFragmentManager is for activity

inside a fragment we use childFragmentManager

```
val manager: FragmentManager = childFragmentManager
CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment().show(manager, CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment.TAG)
```